# How do I get a new identity

Tags: support, user-accounts

I have an identity/account but cannot comment, or post answers. How do I extricate myself? I posted a comment as an answer because I couldn't post a comment, I forget which, and was told off. I once posted a perfectly reasonable question, got a good answer and then was told it was a bad answer. I appear to have been blocked because of the most stupid things, and I can't even figure out how to remove my identity/account.

Comment: maybe try https://tex.stackexchange.com/contact

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th